# Pantalla azul al fondo de aplicacion VB6

Tags: vb6

[image: Pantalla fondo azul]

[image: Pantalla como debe ser]

Tengo esta aplicacion que muestra ese fondo azul a veces. Lo correcto es que salga como la segunda imagen. Que puede ser?

Comment: que fondo de pantalla tienes en tu pc?

Comment: Tengo un fondo de pantalla totalmente negro. Esta relacionado con eso?

Comment: no,  vb algunas veces no acuauliza imagenes de fondo, vb6 no trabaja bien con la tarjeta de video. Tu aplicacion no parece compleja igual y pudes migrarla para aplicaciones windows con wpf, podrias reutilizar las librerias de negocio, solo actualizarias la presentacion.